# Delete product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, ce-1.9.0.1, php-5.4

I am trying to create a one page store and I would like to delete the product page as I have the product description as a drop down on the page.
So is there any way that I could disable the products page as when the person clicks on the product in the cart/minicart it will not redirect him to the product page.

I was trying to find answer but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to make sure the product URL always leads to your custom page is to rewrite the product url model.

Using your own custom module (more on that [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/)) you can add your own product url factory.

Make sure you add a dependency on `Mage_Catalog` in `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace_Module]>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </[Namespace_Module]>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now in your `config.xml` you'll need to add the following node in the `global` node

```
<catalog>
   <product>
      <url>
         <model>[namespace]_[module]/catalog_product_url</model>
      </url>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

Now we can create the actual factory model
`app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Catalog/Product/Url.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Catalog_Product_Url extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url
{

    /**
     * Retrieve product URL based on requestPath param
     * This method is called from several other methods that return URLs for usage on frontend
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @param string $requestPath
     * @param array $routeParams
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getProductUrl($product, $requestPath, $routeParams)
    {
        /**
         * Do whatever magic you need to do here to format the correct URL per product
         */

        return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is really good idea @Sander +vote

Comment: Great answer I will get on it straight away. Thank you +vote